# wget - list of all the files url in the directory recursively but not download them?

Tags: wget

`wget -recursive` and other options are used to download files. Is there a way to download the files' URL without downloading the files themselves ?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `HEAD` requests with `wget -r --spider` to retrieve the response headers without the file content.